# Create a PDF file From a webService

Tags: apex, webservices, pdf

We have an external service that sends us PDF content.

The service gets a JSON and returns a PDF.

The PDF is returning this way :

```
PDF-1.4
%�����
%��ŭв�����������ŭв��������
4 0 obj
<<
/Type /Page
/Parent 1 0 R
/MediaBox [0 0 595 842]
/Contents 5 0 R 
/Resources 6 0 R
>>
endobj
5 0 obj
<<
/Length 0000000677
/Filter [ /FlateDecode ]
>>
stream
x�uUM��0��W�� 
.
.
.
.
.
.
```

I know how to work with files, which I need to decode from BASE64 into my VersionData in Content Version object, in order to save the file, but this is different.

I tried to save the response to the Version Data using `Blob.valueOf` but it stored it as an empty pdf.

I looked some on the web, but I only found how to render a pdf on VF page, which is not what I'm looking for.

I will appreciate any directions \ links.

many thanks!

Comment: Can you add some of the Apex code that you tried when interacting with the service. How are you extracting the PDF data from the JSON file? What you have posted is how I'm used to seeing a PDF if I open it in a text editor. I'm assuming you've run into a text encoding issue.

Comment: Hmm not much information... but you should probably add to your headers something like: `request.setHeader('Accept', 'application/pdf');`

Comment: Thank you guys, I'm sorry I didn't add more details, I will do it later to be more understandable for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't base64 decode this file, that's how a PDF is supposed to look (the non-printable characters are just acting weird). I presume you're calling the web service via HttpRequest and getting an HttpResponse in return. In that case, do:

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
// Fill out parameters here...
// ..then:
HttpResponse res = new http().send(req);
ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion(VersionData=res.getBodyAsBlob(), ...);
insert cv;
```

Using `HttpResponse#getBodyAsBlob` should resolve your problem, and doesn't require base64 decoding or weird UTF-8 glitches you might otherwise get.

Note that the stuff in the SOAP API documentation regarding VersionData only applies to calls made with the SOAP API. For Apex code, you use the Blob data correctly.

Comment: Thank you so much! It's exactly what I was needed.